# How are randomized restarts in local search 4 times likely to give bad local minima?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, np-complete, randomized-algorithms

I am reading section **9.3.3 Dealing with local optima** in *Algorithms* by Dasgupta et al. and the authors mention that in randomized restarts, it is four times likely to end up with a bad solution. They,  then in the next sentence, imply that this a good thing as there will be fewer repetitions needed. Here's the text for context and the referenced figure. The next citation block contains the crux of my question.

> Figure 9.10 shows a small instance of graph partitioning, along with the search space of solutions. There are a total of  $ {8\choose 4}= 70$possible states, but since each of them has an identical twin in which the left and right sides of the cut are flipped, in effect there are just 35 solutions.In the figure, these are organized into seven groups for readability. There are five local optima, of which four are bad, with cost 2, and one is good, with cost 0.

[image: Figure 9.10]

> If local search is started at a random solution, and at each step a random neighbor of lower cost is selected, then the search is at most four times as likely to wind up in a bad solution than a good one. Thus only a small handful of repetitions is needed.

1. How do you end up with the multiple of 4?
2. How is it that the chance
   of picking a bad solution being 4 times as likely a good thing? How
   does this translate to needing fewer repetitions?

Comment: So they’re not comparing randomized starts to non-randomized starts here. They’re just providing an upper bound on the likelihood of reaching a bad solution vs a good one. If we are 4 times more likely to reach a bad solution than a good one, we expect to reach a good solution about 1 in 5 times. The probability of reaching a good solution _at least once_ increases significantly as we do a few more iterations.

Comment: Is the number 4 from the example or in general?

Comment: The 4 just comes from the fact that they mentioned there are 5 local optima for this problem, 4 bad and 1 good.